# Cannot configure serial monitor in Visual Studio on Windows 10 - why are ports not listed?

Tags: visual-studio, serial-port

Docs says after opening the serial port monitor (`Debug` -> `Windows` -> `Serial Monitor`) in VS community 2022 64bit Version `17.6.5`, there should be a list to select the port.  I do not get this.

I have tried mode and `[System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]::getportnames()` in Power shell. I have checked `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM` all are correct.  The ports show in device manager.

I can open the ports I want to use in PuTTY, OpenSerialPortMonitor and SmartTTY. It would be easier and less error prone (forgetting to close a necessary port) to use the Visual Studio Serial Monitor.  But I cannot configure it.